# Nested angular google maps components don't render

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps, ng-content

I am using AGM (Angular Google Maps) and I want to create a set of my own custom components that wrap AGM components to allow high reuse within my app.

When I do this, however, the markers (in this example) don't seem to render on the map, yet I get no errors. I wonder if this is something to do with nesting the components within `<ng-content>`

Can anyone help? I have a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-2za2fg?file=app%2Fvmap.ts) setup. Please see the updates at the bottom for an Angular 7 Stackblitz using `Slot`.

**The TLDR:** When I have nested custom components it creates an `ng-content` HTML element middle man which seems to break `agm` functionality.

My core component is `vmap`

```
@Component({
  selector: "v-map",
  template: `<agm-map flex [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
                    <ng-content></ng-content>
                    <!--agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker-->
                </agm-map>`
})
export class VMapComponent {
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;

  constructor(private loader: MapsAPILoader) {
  }
}
```

Note that if I comment back in the `agm-marker` in the template, it renders.  It only seems to not work when within `ng-content`.

Here is the `v-map-plots` sub-component

```
@Component({
  selector: "v-map-plots",
  template: `<agm-marker *ngFor="let plot of plots" [latitude]="plot.Latitude" [longitude]="plot.Longitude"></agm-marker>`
})
export class VMapPlotsComponent {
  @Input() plots: IPlot[] = [];

  constructor(@Host() private parent: VMapComponent) {
    this.plots.push({ Latitude: 51.678418, Longitude: 7.809007 })
  }
}
```

Is this an AGM issue or an Angular issue?
Is this related to `ng-content`? 
Is there a way around it?

**Update**
As per @Anytoe's comment here is my use case:

```
<v-map>
  <v-map-plots [plots]="displayPlots"></v-map-plots>
</v-map>
```

The idea being I can make a number of reusable maps components that I can then reuse throughout my app where needed.

**Update 2** I read about Slot and thought that could help me, so setup a new [Stackblitz for Angular 7](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-a7h2uz) and used slot but also could not get this working

Comment: What do you want to use ng-content for? Your custom component works fine, doesn't it?

Comment: @Anytoe Good point, I updated my question accordingly.  I need to nest my components and make their templates render, hence the `ng-content`. If I dont use this the plots don't even show in the markup. If there is another way to do this please let me know :)

Comment: I had a play with your stackblitz, and I replaced <!--agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker--> with <v-map-plots></v-map-plots> and there was a pin on 'Hamm'. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Anytoe That is the effect I want thank you. But I want `v-map-plots` to be nested directly under `v-map` not inside the template (essentially the code in via `app.component.html`) if that make sense, feel free to post your stackblitz :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I you are working under the **Angular ecosystem**, I would recommend you to use **ng-content** and explote all its features. Slot tag is for projecting content into HTML5 template tag, the functionality is quite the same, but if you are working under Angular use ng-content since is more powerful and versatile.

Said that, I have watch your stackblitz, it says that ther is **No provider for MarkerManager**. This means that when the AgmsMarkers are created, the MarkerManager provider isn't instantiated.

I have search a little bit, and I saw that this way you compose the components, with v-map and v-map-plots, the order of creation is the next one:

```
1- v-map
   2- v-map-plots
      3- agm-marker
4- agm-map
```

Angular created first the projected content on v-map, so the **AgmMarker is created before the AgmMap**. This is the reason there is no provider for MarkerManager since it is created by AgmMap component.

Given this situation, what I would simply do is **non wrapping the agm-map**. I think it would have no impact in what you are trying to do, since you can compose as much components inside as you want, like this:

```
<agm-map flex [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <v-map-plots></v-map-plots>
</agm-map>
```

I made a fork of your stackblitz showing it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-7jvsjr

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As it is already described in the other answer the issue is that the design of the AGM library is such that it does not work with content projection. When you use it in your case the content elements are created before the component that wraps it which does not work in this case because the `agm-marker-elements` are created first and they need services from the `agm-map` component which has not yet been created. It gets created after the content has been prepared.

I suggest another workaround solution with which allows you to keep your design. For this solution you change the `v-map-plots` component into a directive so it does not have any rendering. This means that you don't need any content projection and instead just get all the `v-map-plots` directives by using the `@ContentChildren` decorator inside the `v-map` component. Then render both the `agm-map` and `agm-markers` in the `v-map` component using the data from the directives.

Here is how this would look like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "v-map-plots"
})
export class VMapPlotsDirective {
  plots: IPlot[] = [];

  constructor(@Host() @Inject(forwardRef(() => VMapComponent)) private parent: VMapComponent) {

    this.plots.push({ Latitude: 51.678418, Longitude: 7.809007 })
    console.log("yo", this.plots);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: "v-map",
  template: `<agm-map flex [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
              <ng-container *ngFor="let vMapPlotsDirective of vMapPlotsDirectives">
                <agm-marker *ngFor="let plot of vMapPlotsDirective.plots" [latitude]="plot.Latitude" [longitude]="plot.Longitude"></agm-marker>
              </ng-container>
            </agm-map>`
})
export class VMapComponent {
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;
  @ContentChildren(VMapPlotsDirective) vMapPlotsDirectives;

  constructor(private loader: MapsAPILoader) {
  }
}
```

Here is also an implementation of this in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-x7pute?file=app%2Fvmap.ts) so you can see it in action.

Comment: This way 'preserves' the structure that Chris has, although, it isn't extendable. With this I mean, that every time Chris add a new component inside the map, for example a polygon, he would have to modify v-map component too in order to support it. this way you finish with a coupled component architecture, that I would not recommend. In fact, the intention of content projection is avoid this particularly use case

Comment: Yes I agree with you that it is not the best solution architecturally. Just wanted to offer an alternative solution that keeps the original design.